# Remove border from Borderless button

Tags: android, android-styles

I have this button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button.Toolbar"/>
```

And this style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button.Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/main</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/secondary</item>
</style>
```

Even though the style inherits from `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless`, the button still has a border.

Changing `Button` to `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton` did not help.

How to remove the border then?

**Edit:**

Setting background of the button is not an option - by doing so the animation of ripple effect is lost.

**Edit 2:**

Things become even more interesting.

Tried to change `android:theme` to `style` as @cadet suggested.

When button is defined this way:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarButton"/>
```

That's what I get:

[image]

The colors apply, but there is distinct border.

If I just change theme to style:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    style="@style/ToolbarButton"/>
```

I get this:

[image]

There is no border, and the style is applied only partially (text is colored, button is not)

**Edit 3:**

Friends, I'm looking for a way to get borderless, styled button with ripple effects using styling approach. Hacking each and every button separately in layout files might work, but that's not the point.

Comment: This! @NileshRathod is right

Comment: @Vasily check my answer, I think it might point you in the right direction. I think you wanna use a combination of a ripple drawable, and a border less button to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @WadeWilson, I can't see your answer. Did you delete it?

Comment: @Vasiliy Check now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, hope out of this one may help you

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_photo_lib"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="startPhotoLibAction"
    android:src="@drawable/library_blau_2"
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
```

or

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. Changing background looses ripple effect.

Answer (score 0):

**set background @null. or set own created background**

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: Tried to set it in the style. No effect.

Comment: Then tried to set on button itself. Works, but the button looses ripple and all other effects. Not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different View instead of Button

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/btn_action_alternative"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: I want ripple and all other button's effects to apply.

Comment: You can add ripple effect using this: "android:background=?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless" and also you can use Cardview instead of LinearLayout (for background shadow). But for touch resize animation, i think you must write some code at onTouchListener method.

Comment: See edit 3 to the question. I want to style my application, not to hack every button in it...

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution, you'll wanna create a custom drawable and depending on the min version your app supports, you'll need to create two, one for Android versions pre-21(Lollipop) and another for post 21(Lollipop). The two files will need to be named identically so Android can find them and match them appropriatly based on the API level. But in the file drawable file for API 21 and above your file should look like such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>
</ripple>
```

This Drawable file is wrapping another Drawable that is your preferred background image or color with a ripple whose color is defined using "?android:colorControlHighlight", which is simple a reference to a default color from what ever theme the current activity is using.

If you need to support pre-21(Lollipop), your drawable file would simply be a selector, with the preferred drawable. Your preferred drawable should be the same background color, or even a transparent color to make sure you can see your parent layouts background color. Similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

You can combine this with a style in order to apply the borderless style to all buttons it to all buttons in a layout... I recommend you use a transparent drawable so you can use this style with all buttons regardless if their parent has a different color background. This will prevent you from making several themes with different backgrounds.

To handle versioning support, or even config support if you'd like custom drawables based on various device configurations, you would just create several drawable folders with a configuration specific suffix. So, for example, drawables only for version 21 and above you'd create a folder called 'drawable-21'.

I found a [website](http://code.hootsuite.com/tips-and-tricks-for-android-material-support-library-2-electric-boogaloo/) that better explains what I'm talking about.

Comment: I almost forgot how much I hate android... I will try to use it later an see how it goes. Thanks

Comment: I honestly forgot about this and moved on. But, since I promised to check it out, I will try the solution once the pressure released and report back.